# Error while uploading flutter app to Playstore - 'android:exported'

Tags: android, flutter

When i upload my app to playstore I am getting an error

```
You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported
```

I have added

```
android:exported="false"
```

in all my activity, here's the manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.connect_one">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
    </intent>
    </queries>
    
   <application
        android:label="Venad"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true"
          >
           
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="false"
           
        />
        
       <activity android:name=".P2PActivity"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.P2PSampleApp"
           android:exported="false"
           
           />
       <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
            This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
       <meta-data
           android:name="flutterEmbedding"
           android:value="2" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
           android:value="Connect_One" />
       <service android:name=".MeetingService"
           android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone"
           android:exported="false"
           android:stopWithTask="true"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Even after the same, it's the same error. Could somebody help me to solve the same?
The code is dart for flutter, its a mobile app.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure libraries you are using in project have added ```android:exported``` . If they have not added it then you will need to declare those activity in your manifest with ```android:exported``` so it will override during manifest merge

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue was i had changed the android app package name in flutter config, But i have not changed in xml & some other places.

But using following library I was able to solve that issue

https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name